# ¿Cómo mostrar una imagen que esta guardada en MySQL en PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

¿Cómo muestro una imagen desde MySQL en PHP?

Tengo el código para insertar, pero lo que quiero es mostrar una imagen por medio del `id`, ¿cómo lo puedo hacer?.

Comment: Bienvenido @LuisChimal, ¿podrías darnos más información acerca de tu problema? ¿qué relación tiene el identificador `id` respecto a la imagen que debe mostrarse? ¿la información binaria de la imagen está en un campo `blob` de la base de datos o en el sistema de archivos? ¿Usas PDO/MySQL o mysqli? Pásate por [cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), te podremos ayudar mejor si tienes algo de código desde el que partir.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento del sitio y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, 
también es muy importante que leas [Ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que esta sea bien recibida por la comunidad

Comment: ¿Insertas la imagen (en binario) en la base de datos o la ruta a la misma?

Answer (score 0):

Crea la consulta que traiga la imagen por ejemplo

```
$image = $pdo -> prepare("SELECT Image From users WHERE Username = ?");
if($image->execute([$username])) {
    $result = $image -> fetchAll()[0]["Image"];
    //todo ese codigo lo puedes hacer como quieras ya cuando tengas la imagen si la quieres mostrar solo da un echo con la etiqueta de imagen por ejemplo: 
    echo "<img src = '".$result."' />";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes traerlo por ejemplo por el metodo GET

```
$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT Image FROM Usuarios WHERE id =" .$_GET['ID']);
```

Luego la imprimes con un `echo`

`images/usuarios/<?php echo $res['Image']; ?>`

Espero te sea util....

Comment: Hola que tal, hice una consulta algo parecida. Te dejo mi codigo para que pues si lo puedes checar y ayudarme por favor amigo.

Comment: Este codigo es muy vulnerable a inyecciones SQL. Mal ejemplo

Answer (score 0):

hice una consulta algo parecida. Te dejo mi codigo para que pues si lo puedes checar y ayudarme por favor amigo.     Pero al momento de mostrar en una vista me da el NOID, no se que esta mal

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM tabla_imagen WHERE id = '$id'"; 
$result = mysql_query($q, $link) or die ("Error al consultar"); 

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
echo $row["imagen"]; 
} 

mysql_free_result($result); 
} else { 
    echo 'NO ID'; 
    }
```

?>  .

Comment: Este codigo es muy vulnerable a inyecciones SQL. Mal ejemplo